# Android sample projects are not appearing on the list

Tags: android, mobile

I have installed ADT bundle for Windows 7,I wanted to run the sample project from the ADT.The list of sample projetcs should be there when i select new -> other->android sample projects.
But it is not showing the list of projects like lunar lander or notepad or HoneyCombGallary etc instead i am getting...
Support13Demos [Android Support Library]

Support4Demos [Android Support Library]

SupportAppNavigation [Android Support Library]

I have installed again new ADT and tried , changed work space still the same thing
i am new to android, not getting how can i get those list of sample projects .

Comment: in new other ... go to android sample project

Comment: @StinePike yes that is what i am selecting and after that i am getting the above 3 things instead of sample projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Android SDK Manager and ensure that 'Samples for SDK' package is selected for the Android version you are looking to get samples for.

[image: SDK samples checkbox]

Comment: No, as I was saying. He won't find the Lunar Lander Sample in that one. He needs "Samples for SDK" from inside api level 4 (not 17).

Comment: I don't think OP is necessarily looking for that specific sample. He said "projects like lunar lander or notepad or HoneyCombGallary etc," so I was simply illustrating the location of one such package. The problem seems to be finding where to install the samples, not which samples to install.

Answer (score 0):

The Lunar Lander sample does not appear in the newer samples. That's normal.

If you want the Lunar Lander Sample and other older samples, open the `Android SDK Manager` and download the other sdk samples and their respective sdks.

The Lunar Sample for instance is only included as part of Android 1.6 I believe (api level 4). It will still work on the higher api levels, but it has to be gotten through that api level 4 and it will only initially appear in the select box once you've selected api level 4 in the `New project wizard from sample...` (of if you dont' want to do that, you can still find it through the file manager by hunting around for it manually by going through the android-sdk samples/ folder. But either way, you still need to have downloaded that particular folder of samples with the Android SDK Manager, the one with api level 4 next to it).